# How to add authentication property for login to directory path when running batch file in WCF?

Tags: c#, process, file-permissions

I have class in my WCF service to execute batch file. when I test to run the batch file in shared directory, everything is fine, the batch was executed, but when I try to run the batch file from secure diretory, I get error **"ACCESS DENIED"**. How to add login property so I can access my secured directory to execute my batch file?

here is my code:

```
public string ExecuteBat()
{   
  string hasil = "";
  ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\Secure\command.bat");
  processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
  process.WaitForExit();
  if (process.ExitCode == 0) 
  { 
    hasil = "BAT EXECUTED!"; 
  }
  else 
  { 
    hasil = "EXECUTE BAT FAILED"; 
  }
  return hasil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ProcessStartInfo` class has properties for `Domain`,`UserName` and `Password` that, when set, start the process under those credentials, something like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\Rpts\SSIS_WeeklyFlash_AAF_1.bat");
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.Domain= "MyCompanyDomain";
processInfo.UserName = "username";
//Secure string is an odd beast, so you need something like this:
SecureString ss = new SecureString();
string password = "p@$$w0rd";
foreach (char c in password)
{
  ss.AppendChar(c);
}
processInfo.Password = ss;
...
```